# overwrite form for django CreateView

Tags: django, forms

Perhaps just another stupid beginner question:
I am having trouble overwriting a django model form which is currently using the following code in views.py.

The code below works well !

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    ### want this instead of line 1 and 2 above --> form_class = PostCreateForm()

    view_args = collections.namedtuple('view_args', ['page_title'])
    view_args = view_args(page_title="Create Post")

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tgt_url_args = MyHelper.parse_tgt_url(self)
        context = super(PostCreateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context.update(MyHelper.get_context_metadata(self, self.tgt_url_args, PostCreateView.view_args))
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        tgt_url_args = MyHelper.parse_tgt_url(self)
        blog_article = Article.objects.get(pk=tgt_url_args.get('Article', '0'))
        form.instance.article_field = blog_article
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

However, I would like to overwrite the form in order to add placeholder to the fields. So I replace line 1 and 2 by:

```
form_class = PostCreateForm()
```

I also added the follwing in forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from . models import Post


class PostCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content']

print('imported PostCreateForm')
```

When I import and run this however, I get the following error:

```
'PostCreateForm' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

You should *not* pass a *constructed* form, only a reference to the form *class*:

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostCreateForm  # no parenthesis

    # ...
```

Django will thus each time *construct* a new form (depending on the situation with `request.POST`, etc.).

If you need to pass extra parameters to the form, you can specify a dictionary in [**`get_form_kwargs`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_form_kwargs).

Comment: Thanks a lot Willem. After making the change and adding a template_name it works fine now.